# JavaFX Image and ImageViewer not supporting jpeg

Tags: image, javafx, png, jpeg, fxml

I created an fxml file with an `ImageView` on an `AnchorPane` using SceneBuilder and through controller class I set the image with the code somewhat like...

```java
@FXML ImageView;
...
void func(File file) {
    Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
    ImageView.setImage(image);
}
```

But the thing is whenever the file is a jpeg it doesn't show. Though it works completely fine with png. I looked up the openjfx doc for `Image`. It says that jpeg's are supported. What's the catch here?

FXML code (test.fxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="1080.0" prefWidth="1920.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="client.Testctrl">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="imageView" fitHeight="1080.0" fitWidth="1440.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Controller Class code (Testctrl.java):

```java
package client;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

import java.io.File;

public class Testctrl {
    @FXML ImageView imageView;
    private Main main;

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public void load() {
        File file = new File("image.jpg");
        Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setFitHeight(1080);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
    }
}
```

Main Class code (Main.java):

```java
package client;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {
    private Testctrl testctrl;
    private Stage stage;
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
        stage.setResizable(false);
       
        showTest();

    }
    
    
    public void showTest(){
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("test.fxml"));
        Parent root=null;
        try {
            root = loader.load();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }


        testctrl = loader.getController();
        testctrl.setMain(this);
        
        testctrl.load();
       
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1920, 1080));
        stage.show();
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: I have edited my question adding what you asked for

Comment: Jpegs do work. Maybe your specific jpeg is somehow broken. Have you tried other images from different sources? Waht is your version of Java/JavaFX and your OS?

Comment: @mipa I am using...
jdk-openjdk 15.0.2.u7-1
jre-openjdk 15.0.2.u7-1
jre-openjdk-headless 15.0.2.u7-1
javafx sdk 15.0.1

jpeg codec
openjpeg2 2.4.0-1

OS
Manjaro Ornara 21.0.3